# Divide two numbers to a range without using parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, range

I have to divide two numbers based on the increment provided by the users, I found an answer which is based on the parts.

I can not use parts as it effects numbers of rows in result, rather I have to pass increment.

Here is my query using parts.

```
declare @min numeric(18,0)
declare @max numeric(18,0)
declare @parts numeric(18,0)

select @min = 100 ,
@max = 204,
@parts = 10

declare @increment int = (@max - @min) / @parts 
while @max >= @min
begin
    declare @newMin numeric(18,0) = @min + @increment
    print convert(varchar, @min) + ' - ' + convert(varchar, @newMin) select @min = @newMin + 1
end
```

Expected output, as you can see in the query my input is min and max with parts based on which the increments are calculating but I have to fix increment like 10 or 100.

```
From To
--------
100  110
111  121
122  132
133  143
144  154
155  165
166  176
177  187
188  198
199  204
```

Comment: Consumable sample data and expected results will help us help you here, along with a *clear* description of your goals. I don't really understand what you asking (there's no clear problem statement), and there is no clear expected behaviour.

Comment: @Larnu this is like dividing numbers between ranges.

Comment: That's not division. It looks like you're trying to partition a range into segments. The code you posted attempts to partition into N segments. Are you trying to partition using the segment size instead of segment number?

Comment: So you want to increment the value of `@min` by the value of `@parts` and stop once the  "from" value would be greater than `@max`? A Tally would be ideal here.

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. Please provide what  the user is expected to input and what the expected outcome of these inputs is

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? There's almost certainly a better way to do this than loops. If you have a Numbers table you could perform an integer division by the size, group by the result and use the MIN and MAX of that group as the segment range

Comment: Also, you have `@parts` as the value `10`, but each part in your expected results has **11** values, not 10. Is that intended?

Comment: @derpirscher Consider an example I have to split numbers 100 to 200 between parts and the size of parts is 100, then the output should 100 - 110, 110 - 121, .. and so on.

Comment: Why? If the size of a partition should be 100, why do you have partitions 100-110, 111-121...?

Comment: @Larnu For excluding last value like 110 in fist split, I am selecting new min 110 + 1 as in query.

Comment: Those aren't parts of 10, @SurajKumar , that are parts of **11**. 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110 is **11** numbers, not 10.

Comment: @Larnu `@parts` seems to be the number of partitions and not the size of a partition.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right, @derpirscher . Would likely be more clear if the values were also incrementing in "10 like" buckets, or a explicit description.

Comment: @SurajKumar explain the problem, not how you think it can be solved. Also explain the actual business problem. The puzzle you posted can be solved one way. The business problem probably needs a different way.

Comment: @derpirscher You are correct but I have to remove parts from the query I am asking and keep increment as input like 10 or 20.

Comment: @SurajKumar There is no query yet? Please provide a clear example what you get as input and what you expect as output. Your current description does not make any sense ... If you want a fixed increment (or an increment provided by the user) just make it so and don't calculate it by any formula. But you can't have both a fixed increment and a fixed number of partitions. With a given range from min to max, one of them will always depend on the other ...

Comment: @derpirscher The input will be the same as in the query but in my actual query parts will not be there and I will pass increment. Consider a business case you are going to update the quantity used to construct a highway between 1km to 2km in meters then you will update the quantity for the first 10m then for the next 10 and so on.

Comment: @SurajKumar add a clear problem description in the question itself. Not the comments. Not something like it, not unrelated examples. There are a *lot* of ways to partition a range using any number of techniques or built-in functions like `NTILE`, `RANK`

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear and doesn't describe the actual problem that needs solving. The code shows a way to *partition* a continuous range of numbers 100-204 into N partitions, in this case specified by `@parts`. It's not very efficient but it works.

Partitioning a range into parts is a popular SQL puzzle so there are a lot of articles over the past 30-40 years that show how to do it for different databases, using different features and trying to get the best performance. In the simple form there are two ways to partition :

- By part count, what you have
- By part size

If you don't want by part count, you probably want by part size. Doing this isn't complicated either and doesn't require slow loops.

Assuming we have a [Tally table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/) named Numbers, with all numbers up to eg 1M, the query to partition a range would be :

```
declare @start int=100
declare @end int=204
declare @size int=25

;with parts as (
    select Number,(Number-@start)/@size as part_id
    from numbers where number between @start and @end
)
select part_id,min(number) as [Start],max(number) as [End]
from parts
group by part_id


----------------------
part_id Start   End
0   100 124
1   125 149
2   150 174
3   175 199
4   200 204
```

First, the Number is divided by the size we want using integer division to determine the `part` it belongs to. The results are then grouped by the `Part ID` and the range limits are the minimum and maximum Number in that group.

Creating a Numbers table is cheap. I used [this script](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained-part-1/) to generate a table with 1M numbers which takes about 11MB only:

```
DECLARE @UpperBound INT = 1000000;

;WITH cteN(Number) AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) - 1
  FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)
SELECT [Number] INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM cteN WHERE [Number] <= @UpperBound;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_Number ON dbo.Numbers([Number])
WITH 
(
  FILLFACTOR = 100,  
  DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW
);
```

Data compression is available in all SQL Server versions and editions since SQL Server 2016 SP1.

The same technique can be used to partition a range into N parts, using the [NTILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function this time :

```
declare @parts int=10
;with parts as (
    select number, NTILE(@parts) over(order by number) as part_id
    from numbers where number between @start and @end
)
select part_id,min(number) as [Start],max(number) as [End]
from parts
group by part_id
```

In real business cases `NTILE` is used to partition results into "buckets"

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 answers here, 1 based on the *original* version of the question (where `To` could be larger than `@max`) and that your goal is that `@parts` is the value of numbers in you want in the bucket (+1). The latter is that you want to split the range into that many buckets, and the *last* bucket is shrunk if the upper value is larger than the `@max` value. Both use a Tally function here, which I include the definition of:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [fn].[Tally] (@End bigint, @StartAtOne bit) 
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        WHERE @StartAtOne = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP (@End)
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6, N N7, N N8)
    SELECT I
    FROM Tally;
GO

DECLARE @min numeric(18,0) = 100,
        @max numeric(18,0) = 304,
        @parts numeric(18,0) = 10;

SELECT @min + (T.I * (@parts+1)),
       @min + ((T.I+1) * (@parts+1))-1
FROM fn.Tally((@max - @min)/(@parts+1),0) T;

SELECT @min + (T.I * CEILING(((@max - @min)/@parts))),
       CASE WHEN @min + ((T.I+1)* CEILING(((@max - @min)/@parts)))-1 > @max THEN @max ELSE @min + ((T.I+1)* CEILING(((@max - @min)/@parts)))-1 END
FROM fn.Tally(@parts-1,0) T
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17f6a4baca31e58e5c5b749aa659c55d)